# PHPDoc vs. non standard string for @property name

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

**Precondition:** My class object has a property "myWorld" which was added by magic methods and is an object of class "PropertyClass" containing the function "hello()".
If I want to use code completion on PhpStorm I can add some PHPDoc before my class so it will look like this:

```php
/**
* Class ClassName
* @property PropertyClass myWorld
*/
class ClassName
{
    public function example(){
        return $this->myWorld->hello();
    }
```

And if I start typing "$this->world->" it will offer me "hello()".

**The Problem:** Let's assume the property name is now a non-standard string (containing a space), e.g. "my World".

The class then can be rewritten as

```php
class ClassName
{
    public function example(){
        return $this->{"my World"}->hello();
    }
```

and would still run as intended BUT code completion don't work, whatever PHPDoc I've tried.
I was expecting something like

```php
/**
* Class ClassName
* @property PropertyClass {"my World"}
*/
```

to work but it doesn't.

I'm aware of the solution

```php
class ClassName
{
    public function example(){
        /** @var PropertyClass $myWorld */
        $myWorld = $this->{"my World"};
        return $myWorld->hello();
    }
```

but I have several of those properties and acutally want to avoid a "3-line-solution" instad of having a 1-liner.

Is there a better way of solving this issue? How can I add a non-standard-string as a property name?

Comment: PSR for PHPDoc standard and tags (PSR-5 & PSR-19 -- https://www.php-fig.org/psr/#draft) does not seem to support a space in entity name: `name = (ALPHA / "_") *(ALPHA / DIGIT / "_")`. PhpStorm also expects single-word properties only.

Comment: P.S. Proper way is to have `$` sign as part of property name: `@property PropertyClass $myWorld Optional description`

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you for you comment but I don't see how the "Proper way" could help here. Adding ```@property PropertyClass $myWorld``` and then define ```$myWorld = "my World"```? Unfortunately this doesn't work at all.

Comment: The "proper way" will not help you with the properties that have more than one word (have a space in it). That was for "normal"/already supported properties -- PHPDoc (current PhpDocumentor and PHPDoc PSR drafts) requires that `$` is present as part of the property name. PhpStorm may support property name without `$` for compatibility reasons (as way back then some other IDEs & editors did not require that).

Comment: Having a space in property name is not supported and unlikely to be supported TBH (at very least it's not part of PHPDoc PSR drafts that PhpStorm aims to follow). You may file a Feature Request ticket to PhpStorm Issue Tracker though and see what devs will say about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: **The possible workaround (requires writing some extra code in your class).** Not sure if it can be applied for your code (if that's our code that you can control & edit or not). The idea: use PHP magic (`__get`/`__set` and alike) -- introduce a new property (e.g. `myWorld` -- without a space) and use it in your code. In `__get`/`__set` methods implement property checks and though some mapping (my property => correct property) use the actual property instead.

Comment: I think we have two issues here. PhpStorm seems to no longer recognise the property as soon as you use the variable property syntax, no matter if the name has spaces or not (`$this->{'myWorld'}->hello()`) so finding an annotation syntax is not going to help. The IDE supports an alternative way to provide code insight information with a custom file format whose name I'm totally unable to recall right now but I suspect it wouldn't help either.